# Are "ectypes" inherently flawed?

Tags: meaning

While browsing the tvtropes.org entry for [Archetypal Characters](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArchetypalCharacter), this sentence jumped out at me:

> A related concept is the 'ectype', a distorted or flawed version of the archetype.

*Ectype* does not appear in my local dictionary and online searches seem to provide a completely different definition:

> ectypal — Copied, as contrasted with an archetypal original. Has a specialized sense when used by the philosopher George Berkeley. ([wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ectypal))

This does not seem to be a common word and I get the feeling that it is still jargon from one field or another. The tvtropes article considers an *ectype* a specifically flawed copy; the dictionary definitions don't mentioned the quality of the copy. I have no idea what Berkeley's philosophies are — is this something he coined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In his [dissertation](http://books.google.com/books?id=Dd2rcwkomJcC&pg=PA51&dq=ectype&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rzsRT7rCO6_YiALWqJXGDQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=ectype&f=false) "Archetypal and ectypal ideals in Kant's practical philosophy," Ryan Showler asserts:

> There is no doubt that the distinction between archetype and ectype is
>   at least inspired by Plato's theory of Forms wherein eternal universal
>   concepts are **deficiently copied** in the visible world.

Showler goes on to state that the British empiricists Locke, Berkeley, and Hume found the distinction between *archetype* and *ectype* useful, and appears to credit *ectype* to Locke. (Follow the [link](http://books.google.com/books?id=Dd2rcwkomJcC&pg=PA51&dq=ectype&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rzsRT7rCO6_YiALWqJXGDQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=ectype&f=false) for the full flavor.)

Comment: Kant + tvtropes = unworldly awesomeness. Brilliant answer.